# How to calcualte the Big-O complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops, big-o-notation

I have been trying to calculate the Big-O of the following algorithm and it is coming out to be O(n^5) for me. I don't know what the correct answer is but most of my colleagues are getting O(n^3).

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1 ; j <= i*i ; j++)
    {
        for(k=1 ; k<= n/2 ; k++) 
        {
        x = y + z;
        }
     }
}
```

What I did was start from the innermost loop. So I calculated that the innermost loop will run `n/2` times, then I went to the second nested for loop which will run `i^2` times and from the outermost loop will run `i` times as `i` varies from `1` to `n`. This would mean that the second nested for loop will run a total of `Sigma(i^2) from i=1 to i=n` so a total of `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6` times. So the total amount that the code would run came out to be in the order of `n^5` so I concluded that the order must be `O(n^5)`. Is there something wrong with this approach and the answer that I calculated?

I have just started with DSA and this was my first assignment so apologies for any basic mistakes that I might have made.

Comment: I don't follow `so a total of` (*$O(n^3)$*) in combination with `total [came out]` *$O(n^5)$* - can you present each step?

Comment: I multiplied the times all the loops run. 1st loop runs` n` times, 2nd one runs `(2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6` times and the 3rd one runs `n/2` times. So the maximum degree of `n` comes out to be `5` on multiplication.

Comment: "loose language" and, depending on interpretation, *not* the way to go. For the third one see, e.g., [BearAqua's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/129684/19966).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1 ; j <= i*i ; j++)
    {
        for(k=1 ; k<= n/2 ; k++) 
        {
        x = y + z;
        }
     }
}
```

The triple-nested loop is equivalent to the summation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} 1$$
$$=\frac{n}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i^2}1)$$
$$=\frac{n}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2)$$
$$=\frac{n}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1))$$
$$=O(n^4)$$

---

In terms of *actual* code efficiency, since `x=y+z` is invariant in the loop, any good optimizing compiler will extract the statement out of the loop (in compiler-speak, hoist the statement to loop preheader), hence making the compiled code run in $O(1)$.

Comment: can this summation method be used for calculating the order of all multiple nested loop problems?

Comment: @RavishJha I wouldn't really call it a "method", but it depends on how you define "all multiple nested loop problems." For instance, it becomes more complicated when recursion is involved in the inner loop.